# Is there a difference between a href and using an styled component with the "as" property as "a" using window.location.href

Tags: javascript, html, styled-components

I would like to know if there is a difference between creating an "a" element vs using a different element with **styled components** and using the property *as* set to "link".

```
<a href="tel:1234, 444"/>
```

vs

```
<button as="link" onClick="getMyNumber()"/>
```

I'm asking this because this url is a composition of a static url and another part which changes depending on the response of the API.
So I will be returning **"tel: StaticNumber + randomNumber"**

Ideally I would click the button, get the secret number and attach that number to my StaticNumber and then make the call.

This will only be working for mobile devices (android/ios) and as soon as the user clicks the button, they will be making a call

Although I see the button element as "a", thanks to styled components, I don't know if it would the same as this

```
<a href="tel: 1234, 444"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to open the link in the button in a new window (i.e. ctrl + click/middle mouse click/right mouse click -> "open link in new tab"). [Power users](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_user) are generally not too happy with that.

Comment: That's what I already tried and it fails for ios and android. Hence I need to think in a better solution

Comment: If you get the random part before the user clicks on the link, I'd simply modify the `href` of the anchor tag with JavaScript as soon as you get that value. If not, using an `onclick` like you have is probably the best way to go, even though it is not ideal.

Comment: yup. I will be doing the onclick solution with window.location.href = tel: 1234, 444